# Angular with Typescript - why to instantiate object I get from server

Tags: performance, angular, typescript

I have a performance dilemma when using new Angular with Typescript. If I use Typescript and I want to have a model.

When I get data (list of objects) from the backend I should apparently instantiate objects based on data I get from the server.
This means I would have to iterate through data and instantiate an object with the constructor.

To me, that would be much slower than just storing the response in the array.
Because, then again in the template, I'm using ngFor to iterate through them. If I use typescript approach I would have two iterations through it.

Am I talking sense here and why should I instantiate objects to store them in the array?

Comment: Typescript has nothing for or against implementing model data as classes (which you need to instantiate). The language offers you the ability to do so (just like javascript does), but you can also use interfaces or type-aliases to represent regular js objects/arrays. It's up to you to decide what's best for you.

Comment: Of course, I'm just wondering why Angular official docs are then suggestion to instantiate object after we get data from the backend. If I don't do that, then I'm missing Typescript's feature for having typed models...it's really matter of performance/readability of the code dilemma :/